# Mix linq filter and sql string conditon

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am working with entityframework core. I am writting a by query with linq.

I have an sql condition which is stored as sql syntax in a string.
How can i "mix" the 2 queries ?

Here is an example.
Let's suppose a have a Companies table.

Here is my linq to sql query:

```
var queryable1 = from c in mydbcontext.Companies
                 where c.Name.Contains('blabla') && c.City.Contains('york')
```

And let's suppose i have this string:

```
String sql_filter = "address like '%word%' or Comments like '%bla%'";
```

What i want to do is to merge this 2 queries like this:

```
var compagnies = queryable1.Where(sql_filter);
```

Do you know how i can do this ?

Please note the queries are an examples. They are more complex in my case.

Thanks

Comment: I think you are looking for delegates: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/using-delegates

Comment: no, delegates are not the same thing

Comment: You can't do this currently (and I don't think they will ever add such capability, but one never knows, I'll be glad if they surprise me:) The only close to what are you asking I see is the other way around, which is supported - start with full `SqlQuery` and apply additional LINQ operators (`Where` etc.) on it.